len([x for x in pyt if x not in pyt]) != 0. How can that happen?
using pytricia==1.0.2
import pytricia
pyt =   pytricia.PyTricia()
pyt['2400:0:840::/43']='l'          # bad block 1
pyt['2400:0:860::/44']='k'          # bad block 2
pyt['aaaa:0:860::/44']='k'          # control block 1
pyt['aaab:0:860::/43']='k'          # control block 2
pyt.keys()
Out[143]: ['2400:0:860::/44', '2400:0:840::/43', 'aaaa:0:860::/44', 'aaab:0:860::/43']
len([x for x in pyt if x not in pyt])
Out[144]: 2

In addition,
trying to access pyt['2400:0:840::/43'] or pyt['2400:0:860::/44'] returns an error.
However:
pyt =   pytricia.PyTricia()
pyt['2400:0:860::/44']='k'          # bad block 2
pyt['2400:0:840::/43']='l'          # bad block 1
pyt['aaaa:0:860::/44']='k'          # control block 1
pyt['aaab:0:860::/43']='k'          # control block 2
pyt.keys()
Out[146]: ['2400:0:840::/43', '2400:0:860::/44', 'aaaa:0:860::/44', 'aaab:0:860::/43']
len([x for x in pyt if x not in pyt])
Out[147]: 0

I guess it's a bug in pytricia but still getting len([x for x in pyt if x not in pyt])!=0 is something that makes you stop and wonder ...
len([x for x in y if x not in y]) should always return 0!

What's the question? What's the actual content of that list comprehension?

No.
Naturally I have the content.
The question is how this can happen. the mechanics behind the scenes...

Well, the length of a list with size 2 is not 0. That's the mechanics behind that part. You'll have to be a lot clearer. Saying that /you/ have the content is pointless. /We/ don't have it.

I wrote the code above so that anyone could regenerate the problem and the lists

the content of the (first) list comprehension is the 2 bad blocks

this list comprehension should always return and empty list!
x by definition of the for loop argument is in y.
But for some reason which I don't understand why, in the first case it does not!

Python doesn't try to be smart. The for x in y iterates over y, the x in y part checks membership. Those are not "optimized out" or something like that. Python will call y.__contains__(x).

@MSalters you decouple the "for" and the "condition" in your answers. The list comprehension [x for x in pyt if x not in pyt] should ALWAYS be empty. Are you saying that there could be an implementation where getting a none empty list as a result is logically sound?

Do you mean that under the hood python uses different methods (for the 2 "in")  that are most likely implemented in the pytricia c? Thus the implementation of those functions may contain a bug that causes the illogical result?
Thanks!

I don't know why nobody has mentioned this yet, but clearly this is due to a particular way that the authors of the module have decided to implement the Pytricia class, for semantic reasons, seemingly. For example, there's nothing stopping me from creating my own weird class Weirdo that implements the iterator interface (so that I can iterate over it via for x in Weirdo()) and also implements the __contains__ magic method to do something you might not expect:
class Weirdo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.range_iterator = iter(range(10))

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        next_value = next(self.range_iterator, None)
        if next_value is None:
            raise StopIteration
        return next_value

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return False # I can do whatever I want here


w = Weirdo()
comp = [x for x in w if x not in w]
print(comp)

Output:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

You're right to feel kind of weirded out by this, because for basic collections like lists that expression would be nonsensical. The only real answer is that the authors of the module decided that iterating over an instance of the class (for x in pyt) does not mean you are iterating over the same collection which is tested for membership when you do x in pyt, and that this is justified because it makes some kind of semantic sense for users of that class to use the class in that way - in this case I believe it is testing for some kind of overlap membership in a trie data structure, which may also explain why the order matters.
Of course, the package wasn't implemented in Python, but in C, so if you really want to get into the nitty-gritty you could look for yourself and try to figure out how they implemented membership checking: https://github.com/jsommers/pytricia/blob/master/pytricia.c#L576


to avoid this problem in the first place pyt =   pytricia.PyTricia(128)
When using only 32 bits trie with IPv6 the pytricia implementation should be logically consistent i.e. len([x for x in y if x not in y]) MUST RETURN 0! I can only assume that under the hood there is a bug. Either refuse to add IPv6 prefixes completely if only 32 bits (insufficient bits for the prefix) are used or have a logically consistent implementation.


Why do you expect logical consistency from an object that is being stretched beyond its limits?

because it allows it. "For IPv6, you can set this value higher (up to 128)". I expected that if it doesn't have sufficient bits for the trie it will either issue an error when trying to use it or do something that is consistent. Guess the implementation didn't cover all use cases.

The problem is that you're using IPv6 addresses on an object that by default is only good for IPv4 addresses.  This simple change will fix everything:
pyt =   pytricia.PyTricia(128)

